# Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi not working after Upgrade/update on HP

Tags: wireless, internet

Yesterday I updated my Ubuntu with the software update tool, after updating and restarting, my WiFi is no longer working. I'm running Ubuntu on a HP laptop. WiFi was working before the update, but now it isn't. I hade the same issue before and I fixed it, but now I forgot how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by following [niranjan7777's comment](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/393#issuecomment-543541830) on [Exec format error on Ubuntu. · Issue #393 · lwfinger/rtlwifi_new](https:////github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/393).

> Basically you have to reinstall rtlwifi_new,so first you have to
>   remove it. Use following commands
>
> ```
> rm -rf rtlwifi_new/ #or sudo rm -rf rtlwifi_new/
> ```
>
> Next get it clone:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
> ```
>
> Change directory:
>
> ```
> cd rtlwifi_new/
> ```
>
> Now change branch:
>
> ```
> git checkout origin/extended -b extended
> ```
>
> Next:
>
> ```
> sudo make install
> sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
> sudo modprobe rtl8723de
> ```
>
> (you will see WiFi is running here)
>
> if signal is weak
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
> ```

Comment: make sure to accept your answer if u were able to solve this issue.